# How do I manipulate amp-notifcation local storage with amp-script

Tags: amp-html

I've done a lot of reading around to try and figure out how to delete and add stuff to local storage using amp-script and amp-notification. In this case I would like to be able to add a date to the local storage and check it against current date activate the notification if the storage is a week old and delete local storage. Then let the notification acceptance reset everything.

Everything I am seeing is that amp-script requires a user interaction before it can be ran. Is that true? Based on these docs (https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/) it doesn't mention that anywhere but the samples on the page that don't require user interaction in the code don't work. Please advise. Amp notification states you should use an endpoint on the server to check the user status. That is bad. That means every page load that a cookie notification is on has to hit the server. If I have a million hits a day that doubles my server load. That is crazy. Please advise.

Comment: I don't understand why you need user interaction? also, use `nodom` `<amp-script nodom>` so it runs faster.

```
const testLocalStorage = () => {
// Do stuff without interaction here
}
testLocalStorage();
```

Comment: https://github.com/milindmore22/amp-local-storage/blob/master/amp-local-storage.js
this may help you

Comment: I got it to add storage items but amp-script doesn't support localStorage.clear(). At least that is what the console error is saying. Thoughts?

Comment: @bradley-w-myers I am not sure if `localStorage.clear().` is supported, but it will remove all local storage, not recommended, instead try to `localStorage.removeItem('keyname');`

AMP Support table: https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom/blob/main/web_compat_table.md

Comment: No dice on removeItem. Not supported.

Comment: So maybe someone can answer this question as well. How come when you nest amp-user-notification inside amp-script, amp-script doesn't recognize amp-user-notifaction children as being part of the DOM? If you replace the notification tag with a simple div it works fine. So when I run the following I get undefined

const $btn = document.querySelector('#ccpaAccept'); (ccpaAccept is a child of notification)

returns undefined in the console.log. When I take it out of the notification tag and put it in a simple div it works fine. Please advise.